# Sorting a LinkedList with no obvious access to nodes?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

Hey everyone. I hope someone can shed a little light on this. I've got a homework problem that asks me to sort a given LinkedList and return the sorted list as follows:

```
private LinkedList<T> list;

// constructor
public SortedLinkedList(LinkedList<T> in){
}
```

Now, I've got the logic down I think(I could use a simple mergesort), but I see no way to access the nodes themselves. Something that comes to mind is a slight variation of quicksort as well, i.e. use the head as a pivot and sort the linkedlist into two smaller ones, repeating and then merging... but I wanted to know if I could do it some other way. Since we can't really access any of the private nodes however, I'm out of any good ideas.

We are not allowed to use Collections or Arrays to sort it for obvious reasons. We are only allowed to use the Java LinkedList and the single private field.

Thanks for any input.

Edit: I would rather avoid using toArray if I can help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is alright you dont need any private access. Threat the list as just list - you have get and set methods.

Very important though is to consider that the linked list is slow in random access! So you need to find a sort that is working with nodes that are next to each other.

Something like bubble sort actually might work the best in that case. 
Not bubble . . The name was different you need to cmp and swap neigbourh cells. Swap sort perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

As you aren't allowed to use other classes, I would recommend you use the bubble sort. Its easier and performance is not that bad. Here's how to use it:

```
public SortedLinkedList(LinkedList<T> in) {
    bubbleSort(in);
}

private void bubbleSort(LinkedList<T> in) {
    // Convert the LinkedList into an array called arr. You should know how to do this..
    // This code assumes that your resulting array is of type int. For others, adjust
    // the code appropriately.

    for(int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                swap(array, j, j+1);
        }
    }
}

private void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int temp = 0;

    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this was not quite what I was looking for. I should've pointed this out in the beginning but I'm trying to aim for something a bit more efficient. My only brainfart was (is) how to access the node links/data without using toArray. I can't use an iterator as that would throw me a nice ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Then you may try using a insertion sort as that sorts the items at the time of their insertion. So it should be more efficient. For the algorithm, read the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I would, but that is not the point of the code. It is supposed to take an existing LinkedList and sort it.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm out of ideas. :) But for your other problem, using an iterator shouldn't throw an exception (I have done this and got no exception). Iterate through the list while adding each item to an array.